# Nextjs 14 - Auth0 actions - api.redirect.sendUserTo not working

Tags: next.js, auth0

I am trying to deny users logging in if their email is not in my database.

This is code from Auth0 action and everything works except redirection.
I have tested with different accounts and it properly checks if the email is part of the array, if not it denies access, but I want to redirect the user to a specific page, not just give ugly error like: [image: Error I get when user is denied]

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const allowList = ['anyemail@gmail.com']; // authorized domains 
  
  if (!allowList.includes( event.user.email )) {
    api.access.deny('Access denied.');
    api.redirect.sendUserTo("http://localhost:3000/noaccess");
  }
};
```

This is how error looks in terminal

```
nextjs-auth0 is attempting to set cookies from a server component,see https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0#using-this-sdk-with-react-server-components
CallbackHandlerError: Callback handler failed. CAUSE: access_denied (Access denied.)
  at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/handlers/callback.js:61:19)
  at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/handlers/auth.js:60:24)
  ... 17 lines matching cause stack trace ...
  at async Server.requestListener (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13) {
code: 'ERR_CALLBACK_HANDLER_FAILURE',
cause: IdentityProviderError: access_denied (Access denied.)
    at NodeClient.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/client/node-client.js:143:23)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/handlers/callback.js:43:29)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/handlers/callback.js:58:13)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/handlers/auth.js:60:24)
    at async D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
    at async eU.execute (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964) 
    at async eU.handle (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)  
    at async doRender (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1333:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1543:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1856:24)      
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1894:32)     
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:271:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:807:17)
    at async D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)     
    at async invokeRender (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (D:\devpako\Web Development\devpako.com\devpako-crud-nextjs\devpako\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13) {       
  error: 'access_denied',
  errorDescription: 'Access denied.',
  status: 400,
  statusCode: 400,
  openIdState: { returnTo: 'http://localhost:3000' }
},
status: 400
}
```